# How to Hide Sender IP Address in Email Headers?

Tags: php, postfix

I'm using `PHPMailer` and `Postfix` in my web server and hosting an application that will often send emails out, like: password recovery, user registration, new orders, orders update, etc..

With `PHPMailer` Is possible to set a value to `Message ID`, but not for `SPF`, since `SPF` values must be set with the `DNS`, my DNS settings refer to the proxy server and not to the web server, also I do not want to setup the MailServer with the proxy server, since it is not a good practice.

Then, my last resort is `Postfix`, should be an option/set in there to help me hide or spoof the real IP address of my web server. any ideas?

I have so far edited the file `/etc/postfix/main.cf` but without any success, also I read part of the documentation --> http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_recipient_restrictions but nothing seems to help me hide the real IP address.

If it is not possible, I will deploy a new mailserver to do the job.

I'm having problem with ddos, that's why I do not want to expose my web server IP anymore, since it is behind a proxy server the whole idea is not to expose it in anyway, but the attacker can easily discover my web server IP address just receiving an email from the server (take a look at the prt sc attached - the parts with blur contains the IP and Domain Name).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Hiding those headers won't do anything to protect your system from DDOS attacks. After all, it's  a web server and to do this job, it needs to be accessible from the outside and it's IP address known, and thus is susceptible to these kind of attacks. It appears from your post that you have no real idea what you are talking about anyway.

Nevertheless, you can do this easily with Postfix anyway:

In `/etc/postfix/main.cf` put something like this:

```
smtp_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
```

with `/etc/postfix/header_checks` having the following content:

```
/^Received:.*with ESMTPSA/      IGNORE
/^X-Originating-IP:/            IGNORE
```

and don't forget to reload postfix.

This will remove all `Received:` lines from your own mail systems, but the first external mail server will put in the address of your mail server and there is nothing you can do about that.

Comment: I know there is other points to take into consideration when the subject is ddos, but right now i'm only interested in solve the mail's problem, one step at a time. Well, I'm only interested in hide/spoof the real ip of the web server, but it seems not possible. I just tried the `smtp_header_checks` in my postfix config and it returns the same result. `spf=fail (google.com: domain of no-reply@domain.tld does not designate IP XX.XX.XXX.XXX as permitted sender)`. And yes, I have no clue about mail servers, that's why I'm asking a question here. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Sorry, but if you try to hide headers in order to get your SPF check passing, this is just complete nonsense. Really, stop what you are doing and use a hosted mail service. Those are cheap and usually reliable.

Comment: Thanks anyway. I was considering Mailgun or Sendgrid, but my volume is ridiculously low, no point to use a mail service. BTW it was good to know it is not possible, I did learn a new thing today here, thank you for your time.

Comment: If your volume is low you can use sparkpost for free